# 1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'pageRequest' on field 'sort': rejected value [asc,id];

Tags: java, spring-boot-2.6.0

2022-01-06 16:18:27 [http-nio-48080-exec-6] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errorsField error in object 'pageRequest' on field 'sort': rejected value [asc,id]; codes [typeMismatch.pageRequest.sort,typeMismatch.sort,typeMismatch.org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [pageRequest.sort,sort]; arguments []; default message [sort]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Sort'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Sort': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]